# How to make a batch program stop Midway

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a batch program that I want to stop Midway. Like I only want it to execute the other commands when they are called like :Command. Is there a way I can do this? I am not looking for a pause, I want it to not play the other commands that are below. I want it to just stop the code in its tracks. So it doesn't play any commands until they are called. Example below:

```
@echo off
:Talk
Echo DONT DO THIS PART UNTIL CALLED
:NoName
echo Going to Talk
goto :Talk
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have so far? It's not altogether clear what you want to do and why it has to be a batch file rather than another type of script.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for ["pause"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490965.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the normal way to do this is `exit` or `goto :eof`. Also `goto` is helpful:

using `goto :eof`(means: "go to end of the script"):

```
set /p "x=Enter a command: "
if /i "%x%"="talk" call talk
goto :eof
echo this line will never be reached
:talk
echo going to talk
goto :eof
:listen
echo listening part
goto :eof
```

using `exit`:

```
set /p "x=Enter a command: "
if /i "%x%"="talk" call talk
exit /b
echo this line will never be reached
:talk
echo going to talk
goto :eof
```

using `goto`:

```
:input
set /p "x=Enter a command: "
if /i "%x%"="talk" call talk
goto :input
echo this line will never be reached
:talk
echo going to talk
goto :eof
```

In other words: end each of your called "Subroutines" with `goto :eof`